# Remove other attributes except count

Tags: java, jmx, micrometer

We have JMX registry in Micrometer.

Questions:

1. Are there any performance considerations associated with the calculations of these attributes: *FifteenMinuteRate*, *FiveMinuteRate*, *MeanRate* and *OneMinuteRate*?
2. How can we remove them except for *Count*? (Just to make sure there will be no performace overhead)

[image: JMX attributes]

Here is a sample of our code:

```java
JmxMeterRegistry meterRegistry = new JmxMeterRegistry(MyJmxConfig.DEFAULT, Clock.SYSTEM);
meterRegistry.counter(name, tags).increment(amount);

interface MyJmxConfig extends JmxConfig {
    MyJmxConfig DEFAULT = k -> null;

    @Override
    default String domain() {
         return "com.example.platform.metrics.test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Micrometer's [`JmxMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/7367d983f397238abaacfb02944f4cc8426a45d1/implementations/micrometer-registry-jmx/src/main/java/io/micrometer/jmx/JmxMeterRegistry.java) uses Dropwizard's `JmxReporter` that creates these values. `JmxMeterRegistry` has a ctor that enables you to specify your own `JmxReporter` and `JmxReporter` seems to have a capability to specify `specificRateUnits`, I think if you pass an empty `Map`, it should not produce the rates above.

Comment: Thank you @Jonatan Ivanov for the reply. I'm new to Micrometer. Could you tell me more about which `Map` should be empty here?

Comment: This: https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/da71539d0956a36f3ccde7cc05c2e891e4dc76c9/metrics-jmx/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/jmx/JmxReporter.java#L139-L148